# Call a function after an asynchronous function finishes executing in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am pretty new to React and trying to learn by making small, simple applications. I am making a simple `React` application which has a `Login` functionality. I am also using `Redux store` and `Redux-saga`. My login flow is:

1. There is a `Login` component that takes `email` and `password` from the user, and on clicking the login button a `POST` call is made.
2. `email` and `password` are sent to the server, if they are valid the server returns a token in the response which I save in `local storage`.
3. If a token is received, action for `Login success` is fired. Here I set a flag called `success: true`.
4. In my front end I check the value of the `success` flag, and if `success==true` then I redirect to another page called `Customers`

**Login Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { loginRequest } from "../../actions/loginActions";
import './styles.css';

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            error: '',
        };
    }

    dismissError = () => {
        this.setState({ error: '' });
    }

    handleSubmit = (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        let { email, password } = this.state;
        if (!email) {
            return this.setState({ error: 'Username is required' });
        }
        if (!password) {
            return this.setState({ error: 'Password is required' });
        }

        let data = {
            email: email,
            password: password
        }

        this.props.login(data); //dispatches a method which then makes the POST call
        //the checking happens before the above function has finished executing
        if (this.props.success)
            this.props.history.push('/customers');
        else
            return this.setState({
                error: 'Invalid Username/Password'
            });
    }

    handleChange = (evt) => {
        this.setState({
            [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        let { email, password } = this.state;
        return ( 
            <form className="loginForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                action="/upload">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                {
                    this.state.error &&
                    <h3 className='error' onClick={this.dismissError}>
                        <button onClick={this.dismissError}>✖</button>
                        {this.state.error}
                    </h3>
                }
                <label className="FormFields label">Email</label>
                <input type="email" className="FormFields" name="email" 
                       value={email} 
                       onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)} />
                <br />
                <label className="FormFields label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" className="FormFields" name="password" 
                       value={password}
                       onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)} />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" className="FormFields submit" 
                       value="Login" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        loading: state.login.loading,
        success: state.login.success
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
       return { login: (data) => {dispatch(loginRequest(data))} }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login));
```

**Login Saga**

```
import { put, takeEvery, call } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_PENDING, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILURE } from '../actions/loginActions';

export function* login(action) {
    const { data } = action.payload;
    yield put({ type: LOGIN_PENDING })
    let url = 'myserverurl/login'
    try {
        const response = yield call(fetch, url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        });
        let tokenObj = yield response.json();
        if (response.status === 200) {
            localStorage.setItem('user', tokenObj.token);
            yield put({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, token: tokenObj.token })
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        yield put({ type: LOGIN_FAILURE, error })
    }
}

export function* watchLogin() {
    yield takeEvery(LOGIN_REQUEST, login)
}
```

The login reducer is very simple.
**Login Reducer**

```
import { LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_PENDING, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILURE } from '../actions/loginActions';

const initState = {
    loading: false,
    success: false,
    error: ''
}

const loginReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false
            }
        case LOGIN_PENDING:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                success: true,
                loading: false
            }
        case LOGIN_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                success: false,
                error: action.error
            }
        default: return state;
    }
}
export default loginReducer;
```

The statement `this.props.login(data)` in **Login Component** dispatches the action which then makes a `POST` call. I want to wait for the entire flow I mentioned above to complete, before it checks the value of success flag, but that doesn't happen.

In the event of a login, how do I wait till the actions of my login reducer are completed before my front end checks for the `success` flag?? I read the docs on `async/await` but I didn't really understand how to use them properly. Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot immediately check for `this.props.success` as you are making an async call, you need to add a check for `success` props in  `getDerivedStateFromProps`

add `getDerivedStateFromProps` in your Login component

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
   if(!nextProps.loading){
     if(nextProps.success === true) {
       nextProps.history.push('/customers');
     } else {
       return { error: 'Invalid Username/Password' }
     }
   }
   return null
}
```

remove below code from handleSubmit

```
if (this.props.success)
            this.props.history.push('/customers');
else
 return this.setState({
    error: 'Invalid Username/Password'
 });
```

Comment: +1 for the approach suggested here. But I would recommend using `componentDidUpdate` instead of `getDerivedStateFromProps` as the latter is only used when you have to make a state change. Nevertheless both give the same result.

Comment: componentDidUpdate will render again when you update your state(in case of failure) then you have to add an extra check to prevent that loop.

Comment: Yes. But in this specific case its a redirect, which will anyway unmount this component and remount another. Anyway, both approaches are viable.

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra this works. Only, I had to use separate variables to store errors in form validation and error in authentication